# how to vertically center an element in IE7 and IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a div element without fixed height, I want to make it vertically centered inside its parent element regardless of its height. I use the `display: table-cell` technique for modern browsers but it seems that this technique doesn't work in IE7 and below. Is there some way to achieve this vertically-centered effect in IE7 and below with pure CSS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us your code, a jsfiddle or a link to your page?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to make it in some other way: http://jsfiddle.net/9TE5t/ ( here `padding:40% 0;` on the parent element)

Comment: @Stano But then wrapper's height depends on its width... Do you want that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set container's `height` value to its `line-height` property, and `display:inline-block` to the centered element.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span>content</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:300px;
    background-color:green;
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px; /* Same as height */
}
#container>span{
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    line-height:normal;
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9TE5t/4/

But be aware that on IE 7 and earlier if you set `display:inline-block` to a default block element (such as `<div>`), it will behave like `display:block`.

Then, you can use default inline elements (such as `<span>`), or use IE conditional comments and set `display:inline` (they will behave like `display:inline-block`) if the browser is IE7 or earlier.

Comment: iow, it's like fiddling with rabbit ear antennas on a TV.

Comment: @Rob I don't understand what do you mean with that but it's a funny sentence, haha.

Comment: The first part of the video here is an example of what coding for IE is like: http://www.howcast.com/videos/403932-How-to-Get-Better-TV-Reception

Comment: @Oriol +1 for the original approach :-)

Comment: @Rob Ah, I'm not a native English speaker, so I though that when you said "rabbit ear" you meant this: https://www.google.com/search?q=rabbit+ears&tbm=isch